# SQL WHERE ... IN recordset

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, recordset

Given a Recordset in VBA that is a result of a previous SQL query, how can I use the result of this Recordset in the WHERE clause of a new SQL statement?

I want to write something like this:

```
SELECT ID FROM MyTable WHERE ID IN <<ID column of myRecordSet>> ;
```

Obviously this isn't correct syntax. I want it to select all the rows in `MyTable` that have an ID matching one of the IDs in `myRecordSet`. Or to put it another way, I'm trying to do something like an SQL sub-query, except the sub-query is a recordset.

Equally obviously, I could build up an `IN (a,b,c)` expression element by element by iterating through `myRecordSet`, but I'm asking this question because I assume that is unnecessary.

(It is fundamental to this question that the list of IDs for the new query come from the Recordset; I realise there are probably other ways to do this kind of thing, but I need to know how to do it in this particular manner.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your recordset is based on some other query from same database, then you can use (myQuery may contain all WHERE and other clauses whatever you need):

```
SELECT ID FROM MyTable WHERE ID IN (select ID from myQuery)
```

If your recordset is synthetical or from different data source, then you just have to build ID list by iterating over recordset.

Comment: It's not synthetic, but I have to guarantee that only items from the recordset are selected, even if the database changed since the query that created the recordset. So reusing the WHERE clause isn't safe.